# How to start countif for different dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have file with over 30,000 rows, i need to count the amount of ocurrances per day per every half hour(but has to be 3:05,3:35, 4:05...) and i have one year of data.
column A has dates, column B has times, and column C has values that i added to check how many occurrences i have every half hour.

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
1/12/19      3:37 PM     12:05 AM
1/11/19      2:27 PM     12:35 AM
1/11/19      5:37 PM     1:05 AM
1/10/19      8:32 PM     1:35 AM
```

this is what i have for my formula which works if i specified a range, but i need it to just start the count every different day since i have hundreds of rows per day.

```
=IF(AND(P3>=$AD$3,P3<=$AD$4),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$3,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&AD$4),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$4,P3<=$AD$5),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$4,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$5),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$5,P3<=$AD$6),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$5,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$6),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$6,P3<=$AD$7),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$6,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$7),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$7,P3<=$AD$8),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$7,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$8),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$8,P3<=$AD$9),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$8,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$9),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$9,P3<=$AD$10),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$9,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$10),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$10,P3<=$AD$11),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$10,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$11),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$11,P3<=$AD$12),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$11,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$12),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$12,P3<=$AD$13),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$12,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$13),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$13,P3<=$AD$14),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$13,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$14),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$14,P3<=$AD$15),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$14,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$15),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$15,P3<=$AD$16),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$15,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$16),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$16,P3<=$AD$17),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$16,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$17),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$17,P3<=$AD$18),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$17,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$18),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$18,P3<=$AD$19),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$18,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$19),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$19,P3<=$AD$20),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$19,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$20),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$20,P3<=$AD$21),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$20,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$21),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$21,P3<=$AD$22),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$21,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$22),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$22,P3<=$AD$23),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$22,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$23),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$23,P3<=$AD$24),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$23,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$24),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$24,P3<=$AD$25),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$24,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$25),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$25,P3<=$AD$26),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$25,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$26),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$26,P3<=$AD$27),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$26,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$27),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$27,P3<=$AD$28),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$27,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$28),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$28,P3<=$AD$29),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$28,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$29),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$29,P3<=$AD$30),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$29,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$30),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$30,P3<=$AD$31),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$30,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$31),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$31,P3<=$AD$32),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$31,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$32),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$32,P3<=$AD$33),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$32,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$33),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$33,P3<=$AD$34),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$33,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$34),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$34,P3<=$AD$35),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$34,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$35),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$35,P3<=$AD$36),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$35,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$36),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$36,P3<=$AD$37),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$36,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$37),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$37,P3<=$AD$38),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$37,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$38),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$38,P3<=$AD$39),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$38,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$39),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$39,P3<=$AD$40),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$39,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$40),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$40,P3<=$AD$41),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$40,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$41),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$41,P3<=$AD$42),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$41,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$42),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$42,P3<=$AD$43),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$42,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$43),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$43,P3<=$AD$44),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$43,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$44),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$44,P3<=$AD$45),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$44,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$45),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$45,P3<=$AD$46),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$45,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$46),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$46,P3<=$AD$47),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$46,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$47),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$47,P3<=$AD$48),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$47,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$48),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$48,P3<=$AD$49),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$48,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$49),IF(AND(P3>=$AD$49,P3<=$AD$50),COUNTIFS($P$3:$P$17,">="&$AD$49,$P$3:$P$17,"<="&$AD$50),"NO IN RANGE"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of expected outcomes?

Comment: well outcome is just  how many occurrences from column B were between lets say 3:35AM and 4:05AM on 1/12/19

Comment: Where are these values `3:35` and `4:05`? Where are you try to display your results. Your question is gaining no traction because it is unclear. Again - please show us a small example of what your expected outcome is so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

Instead of having column C next to your existing data (as shown in your question above), you need a separate table containing all the date+times you're interested in counting as depicted here:

[image: Set Up Date Table]

Step 2:

I also suggest you replace your current Column C data with `=A2+B2` so that you have the date and time within a single cell.

Step 3:

Once that's all done you just need the following formula in your "Count" column:

`=COUNTIFS([RangeWithYourDateTimeData],">=" & [PeriodStart],[$RangeWithYourDateTimeData],"<" & [Next PeriodStart])`

In the formula replace [RangeWithYourDateTimeData] with your updated Column C range (make sure you use $$).
Also [PeriodStart] and [Next PeriodStart] represent the lower and upper bound of the time period you're counting for (replace those references with the applicable cells in your new table from step 1).  In the case of my screen shot I would put this formula in cell `B2`, `[PeriodStart]=A2`, `[Next PeriodStart]=A3`. Then drag down.